# combine text(or char) with user input in edittext for android

Tags: android, android-edittext

To All.
Right now i am working on App which launches a dialog(containing EditText) on any alphanumeric key pressed from keyboard. Now i want that whatever user type should appear in EditText box, which is working properly the only issue that i have is, i want the char key which was 1st pressed to open dialog in EditText Box. I am missing the 1st char key which is obviously right. But I retrieve that char as string separately.
Now wanted to attach(show) that char key to inputted  EditText from user as 1st letter.
I tried this,

```
    {
final EditText search_d_text = (EditText) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.search_text1);
search_d_text.setText(s1);// si is the 1st char key launch dialog(containing edittext).
            search_d_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            search_d_text
                    .setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                KeyEvent event) {

                            if (event != null
                                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                // Handle enter key
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                                // Handle IME NEXT key
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                                // Handle IME DONE key
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
            search_string = search_d_text.getText().toString();
            enterd_text = search_d_text.getText();
                        // collecting  input text.
}
```

What i am getting is eg. when i type MASK, It shows ASKM.

The setText(s1) is always act as last letter.
I want to show the word or whatever user input starting from 1st key.
Thank You.

Comment: code where you open the dialog?

Comment: Thanks for reply, In same activity, just a popup.  i implemented a dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) to detect key and if it is alphanumeric key then showing the dialog.

Comment: so I want code see whether you are passing the char to dialog or not ?

Comment: @DheereshSingh the above code is from Custom dialog itself.  search_d_text.setText(s1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution ,
Just moved edit text cursor position. By
search_d_text.setSelection(s1.length()); i.e to next position.